Difference between implied repo and term repo always negative?
From The Treasury Bond Basis:

A somewhat better guide to finding the cheapest to deliver is the
spread or difference between a bond's implied repo rate and its own
term repo rate. The difference, which would be negative for all bonds,
is a measure of the cost of the strategic delivery options. And the
bond for which this number is least negative (largest algebraically)
is the cheapest to deliver.

I feel like I may be confusing myself here, but I thought if the yield curve is upward sloping, then term repo will be less than the implied repo (because the short rate is less than the yield you locked in with the cash and carry) and hence why it's positive carry. But this doesn't seem to be the case here—what am I missing?

The point here is finding "the cheapest to deliver". It is not measuring the overnight repo versus term repo, it is measuring the implied repo to term versus the real repo to term, across different bonds in the deliverable basket. And there are probably other assumptions inherent here, like net basis is always positive, which financial markets do not always stick to.

Thanks @Attack68. Does it have anything to do with the bond being positive carry to term? I suppose thinking about it more, that’s just a function of coupons received vs term RP, not implied repo, right?

No it does not have anything to do with that. It a comparison between bonds in a basket and the futures price. Bond futures and the cheapest to deliver are affected by things such as coupon level, but also by other factors such as the maturity of the bonds and the steepness of the curve, and potential specialness of some bonds on repo.

Remember that a Bond Futures price must be lower than all bond forward prices (to delivery) adjusted for the conversion factor (or there would be arbitrage).
$Fut = \frac{FWD_i(IRR_i)}{CF_i} < \frac{FWD_i(R_i)}{CF_i}$
where $FWD$ is the forward price of the bond as function of the repo rate (real or implied).
This is an increasing function and so this implies
$IRR_i < R_i$
The $FWD$ function is basically $e^{R \cdot T} B$ where $B$ is the clean price and $T$ the time to the futures delivery.

This is what I stated in my original comments..This theoretical assumption does not always hold in real trading markets. I have traded a negative net basis multiple times.

True, but even to define a net basis, one needs to find a repo rate to the delivery of the contract which is extremely difficult to source. At that point the definition of "arbitrage" breaks down and violations to the above rule are possible. On the other hand, massive violations require a more fundamental explanation (e.g.: is the CTD in short supply?)
